# Why did this work? ( php dot notation )

Tags: php

I was writing some php code after a long sint doing ruby  and I accidently wrote this:

```
[root@ip-10-160-47-98 test]# cat run.php
<?php

class MyTest {

   public function run() {
      var_dump(this.test);
   }
}

$object = new MyTest();
$object->run();
[root@ip-10-160-47-98 test]# php run.php
string(8) "thistest"
[root@ip-10-160-47-98 test]#
```

Now, this.test should have been $this->test, but the compiler was actually happy to let this run.

Does anyone know how (this.test) got converted into a string "thistest"?

Compiled and run on php 5.3.2 amazon instance ami-e32273a6 (CentOS 5.4)

-daniel

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`this` and `test` are implicitly converted to strings, and `.` is the concatenation operator.

Comment: Ahh, the lovely implicit conversions in PHP! PHP never ceases to amaze me. I swear!

Comment: @iconiK With appropriate error reporting active PHP should have thrown two errors a la "Undefined constant `this`, assuming string 'this'." Not that that's really any better, mind you, it's just more obvious. :o)

Answer (score 0):

php search for constant this and constant test, it doent find them so raise an Exception and convert this and test to 'this' and 'test' and joing them (dot is used to join strings)